# C fwrite calculating elapsed Time

Tags: c++, fwrite

I have a question.
I would like to actually have some measure of roughly how long it takes to do a fwrite to a drive.

when i do the following:

```
clock_t begin = clock();
unsigned long long size_t = fwrite(send, 1, transfer_size*sizeof(unsigned long long), wpFile);
clock_t end = clock();
double long elapsed_secs = double long(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Unfortunately, I don't get any different result for different transfer size!!!

My guess is that the clock_t , once it issues a fwrite command, some how stops its measurement, and it comes back again, when I am already done with fwrite.
I do get the almost same measure, whether my transfer size is 32KB Byte or 16MB !
Which I was indeed expecting to see a huge difference.
I wouldn't really want the exact real timing measure (well off course it will be nice to know); and all I care about is to see some difference in time whether I am doing KB transfer vs MB transfer.

Does any one know of any other function that will give me some rough measurement of the actual time being elapsed for fwrite function?

Comment: It's possible that 16MB will take less than 1 second to write, especially if your OS is doing any form of disk caching...

Comment: Is it possible that your `fwrite` call is asynchronous? A quick Google search suggested that it might be, and a call to `fflush` might be needed to make sure that all your data was actually written before you go to the next function (stopping the timer).

Comment: @nosuchthingasstars Does `fflush` actually force the dirty page to be written on disk though? It was my understanding that the flush only guarantees that the changes will be visible to other readers. What the OS does with its page cache should be unaffected. Am I wrong?

Comment: From cplusplus.com documentation: "If the given stream was open for writing (or if it was open for updating and the last i/o operation was an output operation) any unwritten data in its output buffer is written to the file." As to what the OS does specifically, I'm honestly not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that (on most OSes) all writes to a disk are written to an in-memory cache first. Only when those cache pages get too old (order of magnitude 1 second, typically), they are actually written to the disk.

The writes to the in-memory cache are extremely fast. If you need to benchmark the speed of the actual disk writes, you have to sync the cache first.

A method that might work:
`syncfs()` from `unistd.h`. `man 2 sync` says this function does not necessarily wait for the sync to happen, but "since Linux 1.3 it does actually wait".

edit: You didn't say you were using windows :) I'm not very familiar with it, but a quick google search turned up `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` and `FlushFileBuffers` in the WINAPI. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .

Comment: Also the disks have a cache also.  So this needs to be taken into account; as well as time to spin up and find the destination platter and sector.

Comment: Also, take into consideration programs running in the background.  For example, Adobe Acrobat may be checking for upgrades as well as Windows.  Perhaps you may have network pinging or music playing.

Comment: It looks like sync is a system call. Is it? Is there a c++ sync function? what is the sync function for windows. It looks like sync is a unix system call!

Comment: @Rudy01 I don't know that much about windows, but have a look at the links I've added to my answer.